# DateTime property defined in Model is always giving default value in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Model :

```
 public class BR_Model
{
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> list { get; set; }

}
```

View :

```
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, ViewBag.StateList as   IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm", @onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.date)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.date, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "dp1", @PlaceHolder = "Click Here to Select a Date" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
DateTime dd = obj.date;
string state = obj.State;
string Date = dd.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I am getting the value of state but not in date , it is always 01-01-0001
I don't know what wrong I am doing here 
[image: See image here]

**Updated Question** :
After some investigation I got this error 
[image]

Date field is using bootstarp javascript  without any option

```
  $('#dp1').datepicker( );
```

Comment: Is `ModelState` valid? (and why do you have a method that accepts both GET and POST?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke , I checked and model state is false , How to correct it ?

Comment: What is the `ModelState` error - I assume your posting a date in a format which does not match your server culture. And why are you giving the input a `id="dp1"` (its already `id="date"`  by default) - do you have some javascript involved?

Comment: Yes @StephenMuecke, I see the error , Please check my updated question

Comment: What is the culture on the server - based on the `ModelState` error is one that accepts dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`? (is it valid if you enter a say `05/09/2017`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your help , you gave me a lot of hint . Adding  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' in bootstarp works for me